# Uniform convergence of cosine

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_n$ is a sequence of Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$ and f is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ we say that "$f_n$ converges in the mean to $f$" if $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b} (f_n - f)^2 = 0$.

I need to prove that if $f_n = cos^{n}(x)$ on $[0,\pi/2]$, then "$f_n$ converges in the mean" to 0. But I am confused on how to do this. Normally we find what $f_n$ converges to pointwise, which is the function $f$. However here $f = \lim_{n\to\infty} cos^{n}(x)$? Which I'm not sure how to evaluate, or even if I'm on the right track. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: $\cos^n x$ converges to $0$ uniformly on $[r,\pi/2]$ for any $r\in (0,\pi/2].$

Answer (score 1):

For any $\;x\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right]\;$ , $\;0\le\cos x<1\implies \cos^nx\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ , and $\;\cos^n0=1\;$ , so we in fact have that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^nx=\begin{cases}0,&x\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right]\\{}\\1,&x=0\end{cases}$$